# Regex works with online tester, not with BeautifulSoup html

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

## Summary

I am creating a regex to parse a website that contains data about [Android Studio download links](https://android-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/studio/archive_25350a46834ddb86754aba2445ff1359aa7fd8cb296923255092494ac94ef531.frame). As you can see the data is presented regularly, so I wanted to use regex 
to do this in one-shot.

I grabbed a snapshot of the html data and created the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/MC8TOv/1). It does exactly what I want it to do. It actually worked better than I thought!

Here's a screenshot of what it's doing. *Open the image to see it better. Again, here is the [webpage](https://android-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/studio/archive_25350a46834ddb86754aba2445ff1359aa7fd8cb296923255092494ac94ef531.frame) for this regex.*

[image]

The issue is when I codified it in Python. I get no matches. I even used the `generated` python code that the website provides me with my regex and text. That works! However, once I change from the faux html text to a real html data, then my code fails. It's a simple 1-line change and I go from working to nothing.

## Existing work

At first, I used the [auto-generated code](https://regex101.com/r/MC8TOv/1/codegen?language=python) provided with the online tester

I took the following code (near the bottom)...

```
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

and changed it to...

```
matches = re.finditer(regex, soup.text, re.MULTILINE)
```

I've also tried `soup.contents`, and `str(soup.text)`. I've used PrettyPrint (`pprint`) to format the string to make sure it has newlines. Nothing works. It all fails

## Code

Here is a snippet of the autogenerated code from the link above.

**Note:** This code works, but once I replace `test_str` with BeautifulSoup's html string, then nothing works.

```py
    import re

    regex = r"^.*(?:<p.*>(.*)|<span>(.*)<\/span>|<a href=\"(.*linux(?:.tar.gz|.zip))\">(.*)</a>.*\((.*) bytes\))"

    test_str = ("<div class=\"all-downloads hide\">\n"
        "<section class=\"expandable\">\n"

        ...

        )

    matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

        # Ignore the following
        print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

        for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
            groupNum = groupNum + 1

            print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

I have even tried to do a simplier version not based on the autogenerated code

```py
    regex = r"^.*(?:<p.*>(.*)|<span>(.*)<\/span>|<a href=\"(.*linux(?:.tar.gz|.zip))\">(?P<filename>.*)</a>.*\((.*) bytes\))"

    # html_text = pprint.pformat(html.text)
    html_text = soup.text    # BeautifulSoup Object's text representation

    matches = re.findall(regex, html_text, re.M)

    print(matches)
```

## Output

I have always been getting an empty list `[]` when I use the BeautifulSoup object's html string. Always.

Comment: There are no more html tags when you are using beautiful soup.

Comment: Thank you. I had checked `print(html)`, but I didn't check `print(html.text)` but was using `html.text`. Solution appears to be `str(html)`. Making this change seems to work. Just working on some other issues. Feel free to make an answer or else I will in the next few days